# angular 4 - http response from service to component without direct function return

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

My http request has some layer to get the data needed for its request -

UPDATE - I added a observable variable as transportation - I didn't get it to work. It's under the //suggestion 's

component.ts

```
//make a post
service.getUserId(formData)
//suggestion - this.service.response.subscribe(x=>x)
```

Service.ts
    //suggestion - response: Observable;

```
getUserId (formData){
 http.get().subscribe( x => getSubmissionId(x))
}

getSubmissionId(x, formData){
 http.get(...x).subscribe( y => 
  {post(y, formData)}
 )
}

post(y, formData){
 options: formData - append to post
http.request('POST', ...y).subscribe(
 x => console.log('response', x)
//suggestion: x => {
               this.response = new Observable(
                observer => {
                 () => observer.next(res)
                }
               )
              }
 )
}
```

There is no way to get the request up the chain returned.
How can I send the data to the component?
I tried a response:Observable at the top of my service and a this.service.response.subscribe(x=>x), but that seemed to be wrong.

Comment: Question doesn't seems to be clear ! What do you mean to say : this.service.getUserId() call in the component is not returning you the expected data ?

Comment: That is actually a post. It is - but I need to fetch the response from the component. Yet the data is stuck in the subscription part of the service.

Comment: I believe you are missing keyword return in your functions. Since you aren't returning back from functions , you are unable to fetch response. Try using return keyword in given functions.

Comment: If I return the post - the function above that is then not returning the post, but its own values - overwriting the former.

Comment: use `map` instead and subscribe in component, and as mentioned earlier in comments, add `return` to your methods.

Comment: I can not use map - I have to subscribe to the functions to get the parameters necessary for the last one.

Comment: you can use map, you can chain how many maps you like, just as long there is one subscriber at the end :)¨

Comment: But I have to use the result of the request from all functions straight away. So I guess I have to subscribe - unless only the maps are returned and not the subscribes?

Comment: Yes you can use the result straight away when mapping. Just do what you need to do inside the map, return, then it goes to the next map, do what you need to do, return... etc. And in the end the component subscribes.